# jQuery: trouble selecting parent children

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
heading
submenu
heading
submenu
```

`submenu`s are hidden by default. When clicking on a heading, I want to display its submenu and hide the other submenus if they are displaying.

I have inherited Beaver Builder/WordPress so the code is bloated unfortunately.

I'm looking to toggle `#ftr-menu-company.footer-text-links` when clicking `#ftr-hdr-company` and hide `#ftr-menu-product.footer-text-links` if it is open.

On clicking either `#ftr-hdr-company` or `#ftr-hdr-product` I'd like to `toggleClass("hideBlock")` on `.footer-text-links` children of `self`s parent, i.e. the `.footer-text-links` in the same `.fl-col` block & then `addClass("hide-block")` on all other `.footer-text-links`.

This is not producing any effect.

I am not sure if I can actually perform `$(self).parent().children(".footer-text-links").toggleClass("hide-block")`.

Help appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ftr-hdr-company").click(function() {
      showSubMenu(self);
  });
  $("#ftr-hdr-product").click(function() {
      showSubMenu(self);
  });
})

function showSubMenu(self) {
    $(".footer-text-links")
      .not($(self).parent().children(".footer-text-links").toggleClass("hide-block"))
    .addClass("hide-block");
}
```

```css
    #ftr-menu-company.hide-block, #ftr-menu-product.hide-block {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fl-col fl-node-ryu3gqwa2ojf fl-col-small">
    <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
        <div id="ftr-hdr-company" class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-j9orzxfg21dv">
            <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content geot-module">
                <h4 class="fl-heading"><span class="fl-heading-text">Company</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ftr-menu-company"
            class="fl-module fl-module-menu fl-node-2lgy79joxciq footer-text-links hide-block">
            <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
                <div class="fl-menu">
                    <div class="fl-clear"></div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Partner Program</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fl-col fl-node-bmnv7hcwkr6t fl-col-small">
        <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
            <div id="ftr-hdr-product" class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-086d9leqrmbp">
                <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
                    <h4 class="fl-heading"><span class="fl-heading-text">Product</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ftr-menu-product" class="fl-module fl-module-menu footer-text-links hide-block">
                <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
                    <div class="fl-menu">
                        <div class="fl-clear"></div>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Industries</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Use Cases</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's `self` in `showSubMenu(self);` - it's nothing.   Should be `showSubMenu(this);`  Then your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/36d42p57/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use IDs if you're already using classes
- Use jQuery's `.closest()` to refer to a closest parent (or self) before than traversing back using `.find()` in search for a child
- Use `.toggleClass()` to toggle the class
- Use just `.hide-block { display: none; }` in CSS
- Use just `$(".fl-module-heading").on("click", showSubMenu);` and then use `this` in your function as a reference to your clicked Event currentTarget Element (the *button*)

```js
function showSubMenu() {
  const $menuAll = $(".fl-col-content").find(".fl-module-menu");
  const $menu = $(this).closest(".fl-col-content").find(".fl-module-menu");
  $menuAll.not($menu).addClass("hide-block"); // Hide all but target menu
  $menu.toggleClass("hide-block"); // Toggle target menu
}

jQuery($ => { // DOM is Ready and $ alias in scope
  $(".fl-module-heading").on("click", showSubMenu);
});
```

```css
.hide-block { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fl-col fl-node-ryu3gqwa2ojf fl-col-small">
  <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
    <div id="ftr-hdr-company" class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-j9orzxfg21dv">
      <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content geot-module">
        <h4 class="fl-heading"><span class="fl-heading-text">Company</span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ftr-menu-company" class="fl-module fl-module-menu fl-node-2lgy79joxciq footer-text-links hide-block">
      <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
        <div class="fl-menu">
          <div class="fl-clear"></div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Partner Program</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fl-col fl-node-bmnv7hcwkr6t fl-col-small">
    <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
      <div id="ftr-hdr-product" class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-086d9leqrmbp">
        <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
          <h4 class="fl-heading"><span class="fl-heading-text">Product</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="ftr-menu-product" class="fl-module fl-module-menu footer-text-links hide-block">
        <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
          <div class="fl-menu">
            <div class="fl-clear"></div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Industries</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Use Cases</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do that is adding a new attribute to the `div` that you want to toggle.

I added new attribute which name is `data-target` to your fl-module `divs`. So, you can easily define your real target about that `div` in the Javascript part.

The another problem in your code was `self`. To define the element that has action, you need to use `this`. I changed that part and also I made some improvements and simplifications in your Jquery code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div[id^='ftr-hdr-']").on('click',function() {
      showSubMenu($(this));
  });
})

function showSubMenu(evt) {
  $("div.fl-module:not([class*='hide-block'])").addClass("hide-block"); //add hide-block to all fl-modules if it has not already one.
  $(evt.attr('data-target')).toggleClass("hide-block");
}
```

```css
#ftr-menu-company.hide-block, #ftr-menu-product.hide-block {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fl-col fl-node-ryu3gqwa2ojf fl-col-small">
    <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
        <div id="ftr-hdr-company" data-target="#ftr-menu-company" class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-j9orzxfg21dv">
            <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content geot-module">
                <h4 class="fl-heading"><span class="fl-heading-text">Company</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ftr-menu-company"
            class="fl-module fl-module-menu fl-node-2lgy79joxciq footer-text-links hide-block">
            <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
                <div class="fl-menu">
                    <div class="fl-clear"></div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Partner Program</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fl-col fl-node-bmnv7hcwkr6t fl-col-small">
        <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
            <div id="ftr-hdr-product" data-target="#ftr-menu-product" class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-086d9leqrmbp">
                <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
                    <h4 class="fl-heading"><span class="fl-heading-text">Product</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ftr-menu-product" class="fl-module fl-module-menu footer-text-links hide-block">
                <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
                    <div class="fl-menu">
                        <div class="fl-clear"></div>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Industries</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Use Cases</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `e` (better named as `evt`) is a common way to designate *Event*. Avoid using single characters for arguments. And use the proper, more descriptive ones. Also, why to you use `$(e)` ? it's already a jQuery instance object.

Comment: Also, `target` is an invalid HTML5 attribute on a DIV Element. Use the valid `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: BTW the above is better written as: `$("[id^='ftr-hdr-']").on("click", showSubMenu)`